# Cannot open database "DigitSite.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'Lenaire-PC\Lenaire'

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

Connection String:

```
Server=(local);Database=DigitSite.mdf;Integrated Security=true
```

I've tried a bunch of other connection strings and they have the same error or one that doesn't even try to logon to the database I provide.  I'm not sure if this is an IIS issue at this point or a sql issue or a connection string issue.

In IIS7 the this app pool is set to local system

I have my virtual directory mapped correctly

For Path credentials I've used "Application user(pass-through authentication) and I've specified a user and neither has worked, In authentication I've turned off anonymous authentication and turned on impersonation

In sql I've made sure that the user I'm trying to login as has the proper security for this database as "db owner".  I've tried creating a user to sign in to sql as (sql Server 2008R2) but I get errors when trying to log that user in.  Any suggestions?

This seems to be a common issue but I've literally spent more than 5 hours researching this and screwing with settings so I'm a little at whits end on how to get this to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more context. What do you want to achieve? What software? What operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server typically uses logical database name, e.g. you create a database on the server instance (or you attach an existing `.mdf` file in SQL Server Management Studio and give it a logical database name), and you never really have to deal with file names and such.

So your connection string should really be something like:

```
Server=(local);Database=DigitSite;Integrated Security=true
```

using just the **logical** database name `DigitSite` - not the actual file name (SQL Server will manage the file(s) for you - don't mess with that!)

Comment: Wow, I can't say I don't feel silly.  This worked like a charm.  This is literally the one thing I don't think I was doing.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has two places where logins are assigned permissions. One is at the server level and one is at the database level.  You must have appropriate permissions in both locations.

For this error, it looks like the login is good on the server but the database does not like the login.  You are using a windows login of 'Lenaire-PC\Lenaire' so make sure that user is a member of the 'db_owner' role.

```
USE [DigiSite]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Lenaire-PC\Lenaire'
```

If this does not work, you will need to provide more information as to your setup, version of SQL, etc.  This does seem unusual.

Also, make sure that the build process or Visual Studio magic is not overwriting your database changes every time you build the project.  To fix this, I would permanently attach the database to the server.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the input. I'll keep this in mind.